# Drupal Multisite - Subdirectory, Shared Hosting

Tags: php, unix, drupal

I'm trying to set up Drupal 6 multisite in a shared hosting environment.  The main site's location looks like http://www.mysite.com/foo/bar/ and my goal is to create another site using the same database at http://www.mysite.com/foo/bar/drupal2.

I've created a new folder in the sites directory called www.mysite.com.foo.bar.drupal2 and added the default.settings.php and settings.php files, configured correctly for the environment, and I've set up a symlink from the main site's root to the subdirectory, with this command:

```
ln -s . drupal2
```

The problem is that when I go to http://www.mysite.com/foo/bar/drupal2, I just get the main site at http://www.mysite.com without triggering the installer.

What do I need to change to get the multisite working?

Comment: This may be of some help: http://www.drupalcoder.com/story/205-drupal-multisite-in-subfolders

Comment: Already been there - and I don't have access to Apache configuration settings, and can't use the Alias settings.

Answer (score 0):

There's a whole section on [Multu-site how-tos](http://drupal.org/node/43816) on drupal.org.

The reason what you did is not working is that you symlinked the entire site, so there wont be a difference, you'll get the same settings.php file with the same db settings etc.

The `magic` happens in the sites folder, take a look at [this handbook page](http://drupal.org/node/70861), it looks like this is what you are after.

Comment: I've been through all that information, and it hasn't helped.  I just get a 404 error when I try to visit the second site's url without the symlink.

Answer (score 0):

Probably You need to set the `$base_url` to *http://www.mysite.com/foo/bar/drupal2* in settings.php in the ".../drupal2" installation.

Comment: Are You 100% sure that the `$baseurl` is set correctly (i.e. settings.php could be set in the wrong subdirectory of sites/ - http://drupal.org/node/53705) and known by Drupal? Try to output this variable within site content or block to see if it points to .../drupal2.

I used to have a similar setup with 1 installation in a main directory, and a few following in the subdirectories. Every time, setting correctly the `$base_url` did the thing.